# PowerShell Get-ChildItem on folder that does not exist behaves different with the -recurse flag

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am testing a Power Shell script to clean out a folder and I noticed some unexpected (to me) behavior when i used the - recurse flag

I have read the help files and done some searching but cant find an explanation for what is happening here.

Consider these 3 Power Shell commands:

```
 Get-ChildItem -Path  C:\folderThatDoesNotExist -recurse

 Get-ChildItem -Path  C:\folderThatDoesNotExist\ -recurse

 Get-ChildItem -Path  C:\folderThatDoesNotExist\* -recurse
```

The first command appears to search all of C:\ and there are a bunch of access denied errors for folders outside C:\folderThatDoesNotExist (eg c:\windows)

The second errors out with c:\f does not exist

The third errors out with c:\folderThatDoesNotExist\ not found

I expected all 3 to give an error of c:\folderThatDoesNotExist\ Path not found. Why do the first 2 give different errors?

Comment: Use `-Include *`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1st command: `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\folderThatDoesNotExist -recurse`**

You're seeing an unfortunate nod to `cmd.exe`'s `dir` command, where the last path component of the `-Path` argument is interpreted as a *pattern* to be searched for *on all levels of the subtree hierarchy* - even when that last component *doesn't* contain wildcard characters such as `*` and `?`.

This highly problematic behavior is discussed in [GitHub issue #5699](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5699).

To avoid it, **use `-LiteralPath`** instead of `-Path`.
**Caveat**: [user3608068](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3608068/user3608068) reports that this **doesn't help in PowerShell v4** (and possibly all lower versions).

---

**2nd command: `Get-ChildItem -Path  C:\folderThatDoesNotExist\ -recurse`**

The behavior is more sensible - an error occurs - but the error message complains about only *part* of the  path, `C:\f`.

This is in itself a bug, but a harmless one (if you omit `-Recurse`, the error message quotes the correct, full path).

---

**3rd command: `Get-ChildItem -Path  C:\folderThatDoesNotExist\* -recurse`**

This command exhibits the expected behavior: `C:\folderThatDoesNotExist` is correctly interpreted as a *directory* path that doesn't exist (whose child elements are being requested with wildcard `*`), and the error message correctly reflects that.